# Restrict Artifact Upload to a single repository

Tags: nexus

I am using Nexus OSS 2.13.0-01. I want to restrict Artifact Upload for a single user to a single repository (All other users should not be able to upload Artifacts to any of the repositories).

I followed the documentation to create custom repository target, custom privileges and custom roles. However, I see that 'Artifact Upload' is a Privilege of the type 'Application'. If I understand it right, I can not make 'Artifact Upload' applicable to a single Nexus repository but on the entire Nexus Application.

Hence, I am getting 'Artifact Upload' tab for every repository in Nexus and not a single repository.

How do I achieve it?

Cheers,
Anantha

Answer (score 0):

The "artifact upload" privilege controls whether or not the upload UI tab is visible.  It does not grant privileges to actually upload anything, for that the user needs create or update privileges in the repository.

It is not practical to make the upload UI appear and disappear based on whether a user has write privileges. Checking to see if user has upload permissions is actually quite complex when you consider how nexus repository permissions work. They consist of...

**Repository Targets:**

- A regular expression describing patterns of artifacts that can be
  uploaded (e.g, "/com/foo/somecompany/someproject/.*"
- A repository type which is allowed (e.g, "maven2", or "any content".

**Repository Target Privileges:**

- A repository target
- A repository where the target applies, or "all repositories"

Further complicating matters is that repository privileges are transitive. Privileges applied to group repositories also apply to the groups member repositories. So a privilege granted for a group repository is also granted for the groups members.

So in the general case we can't tell if a user has permission to upload something until they actually try to upload it.